# AbstractRoutingDatasource and hibernate.dialect with multiples datasources

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In my Spring Java Config file,i use **AbstractRoutingDatasource** successfully to switch multiple databases connections.

```
public MyRoutingDataSource myRoutingDataSource() {
    MyRoutingDataSource dataSource = new MyRoutingDataSource();
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource());
    dataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    return dataSource;
}
```

But when i want specific SQL requests that differs from datasources PostgreSQL/Oracle etc.. (like pagination limit/rowNums), i have to associated a specific **hibernate dialect**.

```
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect");

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("fr.appli.model");
    factory.setDataSource(myRoutingDataSource());
```

My question is how can i change hibernate dialect in my EntityManager, when i change datasource from with AbstractRoutingDatasource ? Is it possible to do it programmatically ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate this? Did you solve the problem? I am struggling to get this working with various dialects but cannot find solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think to achive this you will need multiple datasource configuration files and each database has its own SessionFactory object in an DAO which will permof DB operations.

For example :

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory1 = new  Configuration().configure("oracleconfig.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

SessionFactory sessionFactory2 = new Configuration().configure("mysqlconfig.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Yes, using an DAO it is possible to configure multiple datasources condition to that you will have that many `SessionFactory`s.